# How to get BoldedDates on my MonthCalendar?

Tags: c#, calendar, cells, bold

I'm trying to bold some dates on my MonthCalendar. I do get all of my dates perfectly from my files name but it seems like I just can't bold the cells. Is there someone who could explain me what am I doing wrong ? 
Here is the code I'm using on my Form_Load function :

```
        MonthCalendar c = new MonthCalendar();
        lbl_date.Text = c.TodayDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");

        loadEventDisplay();

        string dirPath = @"E:\Calendar\";
        List<string> files = new List<string>(Directory.EnumerateFiles(dirPath));
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            string year = file.Substring(18, 4);
            string month = file.Substring(15, 2);
            string day = file.Substring(12, 2);

            DateTime[] dt = new DateTime[]   
            {
                    new DateTime(Int32.Parse(year), Int32.Parse(month), Int32.Parse(day))
            };

          // The date format I am using on that line is actually the same that works with the graphic interface
            c.AddBoldedDate(DateTime.Parse(day+"/"+month+"/"+year)); 
            c.UpdateBoldedDates();
```

Thanks by advance !

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
__Always__ tag your question correctly!

Comment: Your code looks fine. Most likely your dates are not. But, of course it makes no sense to init the array all the time. Instead use a List<DateTime>, declare it outside of the loop and add it as.ToaRRay() after the loop!

Comment: I've been trying that way but it seems like the BoldedDates property is not working. Thanks for your time anyway.

Comment: Hm, well I tried it and it surely does work here.

Answer (score 0):

You want to just use the Month calendar control perhaps

Here is a code exert to help:

```
DateTime[] myDates = {myDate1, myDate2};

calendar.BoldedDates = myDates;
```

Hope that helps.
See [Here](https://www.dotnetperls.com/monthcalendar)

Comment: I've been created a test button to see what's wrong more precisely but my date is still not bolded. Here is the code : 
        `private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DateTime[] dateTimes = new DateTime[]
            {
                new DateTime(2017, 2, 10),
            };
            cal.BoldedDates = dateTimes;
            cal.UpdateBoldedDates();
        }`